# What's the idiomatic way of calling a function with many arguments?

Tags: coding-style, lisp

In Lisp (any lisp dialect will do) what's the idiomatic way of calling a function with *many* args?

By many I mean exceeding the 80 character limit.

Say we have an example function called `foo-func` that takes a variable number of arguments

```
(foo-func 'foo 'bar 'baz 'qux 'foo-bar 'foo-baz 'foo-qux 'bar-foo 'bar-baz 'you-get-the-idea)
```

How would one normally arrange the args if not on a long incomprehensible line?

**NOTE** this is not a question about personal preference, it's about how it's recommended it's done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, it would be aligned like this:

```
(foo-func 'foo
          'bar
          'baz
          'qux
          'foo-bar
          'foo-baz
          'foo-qux
          'bar-foo
          'bar-baz
          'you-get-the-idea)
```

In some cases, you might put several arguments that belong together on one line:

```
(foo-func 'foo
          'bar
          'baz
          'qux
          'foo-bar 'foo-baz 'foo-qux
          'bar-foo 'bar-baz
          'you-get-the-idea)
```

However, any function that has more than a few arguments would often make heavy use of keyword parameters:

```
(foo-func 'foo
          'bar
          'baz
          'qux
          :barista 'foo-bar
          :bazaar 'foo-baz
          :quxfrog 'foo-qux
          :baroofa 'bar-foo
          :barazza 'bar-baz
          :say-what 'you-get-the-idea)
```

Here, you could perhaps put the required parameters on one line:

```
(foo-func 'foo 'bar 'baz 'qux
          :barista 'foo-bar
          :bazaar 'foo-baz
          :quxfrog 'foo-qux
          :baroofa 'bar-foo
          :barazza 'bar-baz
          :say-what 'you-get-the-idea)
```

Comment: Plus, if you have a function with 11 arguments, you're probably Doing It Wrong.

Comment: @Xach a required argument and 5 keyword arguments would easily lead to 11 "arguments" passed to the function, and that's not all the unreasonable for some kinds of constructors.  But yes, if these are all required arguments, something should probably be refactored.

Comment: I know OP already accepted the answer. But he says that the function takes a variable number of arguments. So maybe he needs a list. Or `(define (foo . args) args)`

Comment: @Rptx The answer would be the same since he's asking about coding style (how to not have it on one single line when calling) and not how to have variable number of arguments in a definition.

Comment: @Xach I know that it's probably coded wrong if there are 11 args, but I have this variadic convenience function I use in my emacs config, that I just add stuff to as I progress; rather than writing another repeated line of code with a different argument, DRY code tends to be less error-prone after all. Hence this question